Complexity of finding the sparsest square-root (Cholesky-like) decomposition for a matrix
I have a symmetric positive semidefinite $n\times n$ matrix $A$ which I would like to decompose into a $n\times m$ matrix $G$ so that $G G^{T} = A$.
The Cholesky decomposition is an efficient algorithm running in time $O(n^3)$ which outputs such a matrix $G$ that is always upper-triangular with $m=n$. Here, I would like to consider making $G$ as sparse as possible. Namely, I would want each column of $G$ (we will have $m$ columns with $n$ elements each) to have at most $k$ non-zero elements. Obviously, if $k$ is too small, there will be no such decomposition.
Question: What is the computational complexity of the problem of finding $G$ that is $k$-sparse in this sense?
Since I know that minimization of the $L_0$ norm for an underdetermined linear equation is NP-hard https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539792240406 , it feels like this problem too may be. On the other hand, the Cholesky decomposition is quite close to what I want (but of course without the ability to make the output sparse), so I was wondering if anything is known about the complexity of this problem. I considered reducing the problem to the linear equation case, but that failed.
I also found the following stackoverflow thread with all the right keywords,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69386603/complexity-of-sparse-matrix-cholesky-decomposition
but it seems like people usually ask about cases where $A$ is assumed to be sparse and questioning whether that sparsity can be exploited or not, which is kind of the opposite thing from what I am asking here.
Any information/thoughts will be welcome. Thank you!
